# Creating an index in my crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report where I list peoples addresses and some extra information.
At the footer of the report I have a sub report with just the names of people sorted by first name.
I would like to put an A before all the people with names that start with A and a B before people that has names that start with a B and so on. Is there a function built in for this?

Something like this:

- A
- Adam
- Anton
- B
- Bob
- Bert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation and your example are different, below solution will give output of your example.

Create a formula to extract first character.

@firstcharacter  //formula name

Assuming field name as `field1`.

`field1 [1]`

Now in your subreport group by this formula and place field1 in details.

If this is not you are looking for let me know.

Comment: Here is a step by step link if anyone needs it. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic124.html